# Как создать таймер для пользователя?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня бот для вк. Мне нужно что бы при вводе команды test бот ответил пользователю "Работаю". Но если пользователь еще раз ввел ему высветило "Подождите 10 минут". ПОсле того как пройдет 10 минут пользователь может снова писать test.
Вопрос:
Как сделать что бы пользователю после ввода команды, эта же команда была доступна через 10 минут? Node js

Comment: Какой команды? Где ввода? В REPL'е?

Comment: Исправил все. Смотри

Comment: Ну, тут можно много чего придумать, но в общих чертах - после исполнения команды, сохранять время, когда ее можно использовать снова. Соответственно, при получении команды проверять, если уже можно, то выполнить ее снова, иначе попросить подождать.

Answer (score 0):

Если в ноде есть класс `Date` и его статичный метод `now()`:

1. Объявляете в воркере (или как оно в ноде называется) примерно такой объект с данными пользовательских команд

   ```
   const cmdData = {
     'test': { timeout: 6e5, lastAccessTime: 0 }, 
     ... 
   };
   ```
2. При выполнении команды пользователя, проверяете, прошло ли заданное
   количество времени

   ```
   let cd = cmdData[command], 
       tNow = Date.now(); 
   if (tNow - cd.lastAccessTime > cd.timeout) {
     cd.lastAccessTime = tNow; 
     // вывод "Работаю" и выполнение действий 
   }
   else 
     // вывод "Подождите 10 минут"
   ```